# remove part of URL string with regex in column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to clean up some urls to remove the unique tracking codes so that in reporting they can be counted in a group rather than 1000's of individual pages.

the code to remove is in the middle of the url and varies in length.

example url is

https://www.website.co.uk/product/?commcodeABBB/home-page/

I am trying to get this

https://www.website.co.uk/product/home-page/

I have similar code working for removing the end of a url string:

```
df["URL"] = df["URL"].str.replace('\/id.*','/',regex=True)
```

I have tried to modify it for my new scenario.

```
df["URL"] = df["URL"].str.replace('\/\?commcode.{0,5}','/',regex=True)
```

In this scenario the regex `\/\?commcode.{0,5}` does select ?commcodeABBB/ however the length of code string in my URLs vary so it won't work on everything.

I cannot work out how to write it so that it takes everything from ?commcode up to and including the next /. I looked at \w \W for 'in-between' however it doesn't recognise / only alphanumeric characters.

I have read many many other posts about similar issues but nothing quite addresses this that I can find. I cannot use code that counts from start or end of the string as length changes, as does the number of / in the url so I cannot use 'between 2nd and 3rd / method.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
df["URL"] = df["URL"].str.replace(r'/\?commcode[^/]*', '')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/lr3BL7/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \?                       '?'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  commcode                 'commcode'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/]*                    any character except: '/' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: that is brilliant! i've spent all day trying to work this out. thank you. I also like regex101.com much more than Pythex which I was using as you can hover over the characters. i used your proof link to test adding extra characters and numbers to the string and it worked for all of the scenarios. I don't understand why the greedy match * comes last (after the match single character /) but it works

Comment: @MizzH See explanation, `[^/]` matches any single character that is not `/`, and `*` allows matching zero or more of such consecutive characters.

Comment: this also works if other characters such as = - and ? are included in the string

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
'\/\?commcode[A-Za-z0-9]*'
```

to specify which character groups you want included.

Comment: thank you. this works well also. and answers my question. I also tested it in regex101